# How to implement division with round-towards-infinity in Python

Tags: python, math, floating-point, rounding, division

I want 3/2 to equal 2 not 1.5

I know there's a mathematical term for that operation(not called rounding up), but I can't recall it right now. 
Anyway, how do i do that without having to do two functions?

ex of what I do NOT want:

```
answer = 3/2 then math.ceil(answer)=2 (why does math.ceil(3/2)=1?)
```

ex of what I DO want:

```
 "function"(3/2) = 2
```

Comment: If you want 3 <operation> 2 = 2, that's certainly NOT division. PS `math.ceil(3/2) = 1` because `3/2 = 1` (integer division), so you are ceiling 1, not 1.5

Comment: This **is** a legitimate form of rounding, and the term for it is ["round towards infinity" (or "round away from zero")](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_away_from_zero). Most of you are beating up on the OP unfairly. Yes, there is no way to do this in native Python with one builtin or fn.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he just wants to define a function like `divideup = lambda x, y: round(float(x) / y)` or `divideup = lambda x, y: math.ceil(float(x) / y)` depending on the rounding he wants.

Comment: @smci From a strictly mathematical point of view, I have never seen division being rounded up (or towards infinity), but down is fairly common (ie: quotient). Similarly, no programming language I know has a built-in round-towards-infinity-division operator.

Comment: @OP: clarify whether you want -3/2 to round to -2 or -1 (or that you don't care about negative operands, which makes it equivalent to round-upwards, on positive operands anyway).

Comment: @Null, I did an MSEE degree involving this and I spend months reading about such implementations. A good text is ["Computer Arithmetic Algorithms" by Israel Koren](http://www.ecs.umass.edu/ece/koren/arith/). You're confusing 'mathematical operation' with 'the usual implementation of floating-point arithmetic'.

Comment: The [IEEE-754 floating-point standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008#Rounding_algorithms) (which is the golden reference for implementing computer arithmetic in software and/or hardware) explicitly allows **round-away-from-zero** (round-towards-infinity) as one possible rounding mode. All the downvoting here is mistaken.

Comment: @smci By "mathematical operation" I mean math outside of the computer field. And again, can you show me a language where division rounds towards infinity (or has a built-in operator for this)? I ask this from genuine curiosity.

Comment: @Null, you're confusing terms. If you program low-level C macros or assembly code on DSP chips, people do this every day of the week (reference below). If you mean this is not seen in 'high-level language specifications', yes that's right. There are tons of mathematical operations for which there is no builtin direct high-level-language arithmetic operation, such as 2^N-point Fast Fourier Transforms, convolutions, correlations, Laplace transforms, you name it... The point is that the OP's question is legit (although rarely seen), and the downvotes are mistaken.

Comment: @smci I see. But it's probably because this is rarely, if ever, seen in high-level programming that it strikes people as an unusual thing to ask. I didn't downvote him though.

Comment: No problem. Some references: [EETimes "An introduction to different rounding algorithms"](http://www.eetimes.com/design/programmable-logic/4014804/An-introduction-to-different-rounding-algorithms), or read the reference manual to most [DSP chips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal_processor#Modern_DSPs), e.g. Texas Instruments C6xxx family, ARM Cortex etc. The downvotes appear to be disappearing as we speak ;-)

Comment: @Null, just to point out your first statement above was incorrect: _"If you want 3 <operation> 2 = 2, that's certainly NOT division."_ It actually is division (division-with-round-away), just not the flavor you're familiar with. Enough said.

Comment: @smci, maybe you could summarize your comments in an answer?

Comment: What do you want 1.4 and 2.5 to be rounded to?

Comment: Though it should really be moot whether other people do division this way -- programming is not just about duplicating the exact behavior of other people.

Answer (score 16):

*To give a short answer...*

Python only offers native operators for two types of division: "true" division, and "round down" division. So what you want isn't available as a single function. However, it is possible to easily implement a number of different types of division-with-rounding using some short expressions.

Per the title's request: given strictly integer inputs, "round up" division can be implemented using `(a+(-a%b))//b`, and "round away from zero" division can be implemented using the more complex `a//b if a*b<0 else (a+(-a%b))//b`. One of those is probably what you want. As to why...

---

*To give a longer answer...*

First, let me answer the subquestion about why `3/2==1` and `math.ceil(3/2)==1.0`, by way of explaining how the Python division operator works. There are two main issues at play...

**`float` vs `int` division:** Under Python 2, division behaves differently depending on the type of the inputs. If both `a` and `b` are integers, `a/b` performs "round down" or "floor integer" division (eg `3/2==1`, but `-3/2==-2`). This is equivalent to `int(math.floor(float(a)/b))` .

But if at least one of `a` and `b` are floats, Python performs "true" division, and gives you a `float` result (eg `3.0/2==1.5`, and `-3.0/2==-1.5`). This is why you'll sometimes see the construction `float(a)/b`: it's being used to force true division even both inputs are integers (eg `float(3)/2==1.5`). This is why your example `math.ceil(3/2)` returns `1.0`, whereas `math.ceil(float(3)/2)` returns `2.0`. The result has already been rounded down before it even reaches `math.ceil()`.

**"true division" by default**: In 2001, it was decided ([PEP 238](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/)) that Python's division operator should be changed so that it always performs "true" division, regardless of whether the inputs are floats or integers (eg, this would make `3/2==1.5`). In order to not break existing scripts, the change in default behavior was deferred until Python 3.0; in order to get this behavior under Python 2.x, you have to enable it per-file by adding `from __future__ import division` to the top of the file. Otherwise the old type-dependant behavior is used.

But "round down" division is still frequently needed, so the PEP didn't do way with it entirely. Instead, it introduced a new division operator: `a//b`, which *always* performs round down division, even if the inputs include floats. This can be used without doing anything special under both Python 2.2+ and 3.x.

---

*That out of that way, division-with-rounding:*

In order to simplify things, the following expressions all use the `a//b` operator when working on integers, since it will behave the same under all python versions. As well, I'm making an assumption that `0<=a%b<b` if `b` is positive, and `b<=a%b<=0` if b is negative. This is how Python behaves, but other languages may have slightly different modulus operators.

The four basic types of integer division with rounding:

- **"round down"** aka "floor integer" aka "round to minus infinity" divsion: python offers this natively via `a//b`.
- **"round up"** aka "ceiling integer" aka "round to positive infinity" division: this can be achieved via `int(math.ceil(float(a)/b))` or `(a+(-a%b))//b`. The latter equation works because `-a%b` is 0 if `a` is a multiple of `b`, and is otherwise the amount we need to add to `a` to get to the next highest multiple.
- **"round towards zero"** aka "truncated" division - this can be achieved via `int(float(a)/b)`. Doing this without using floating point is trickier... since Python only offers round-down integer division, and the `%` operator has a similar round-down bias, we don't have any non-floating-point operators which round symmetrically about 0. So the only way I can think of is to construct a piecewise expression out of round-down and round-up: `a//b if a*b>0 else (a+(-a%b))//b`.
- **"round away from zero"** aka "round to (either) infinity" division - unfortunately, this is even trickier than round-towards-zero. We can't leverage the truncating behavior of the `int` operator anymore, so I can't think of a simple expression even when including floating-point ops. So I have to go with the inverse of the round-to-zero expression, and use `a//b if a*b<0 else (a+(-a%b))//b`.

Note that if you're only using positive integers, `(a+b-1)//b` provides round up / away from zero even more efficiently than any of the above solutions, but falls apart for negatives.

Hope that helps... and happy to make edits if anyone can suggest better equations for round to/away from zero. I find the ones I have particularly unsatisfactory.

Comment: Those integer ones at the end -- that's the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I refactored my answer to give more details, and emphasize that expression at the top. Hope I didn't ruin the answer :)

Comment: For positive integers only, how about `(a // b)+1`?

Comment: @Devy For "round up" division, ``(a // b)+1`` returns wrong value for multiples of b -- for example ``(10//5)+1`` returns 3, rather than 2.

Answer (score 4):

Integral division in Python 3:

`3 // 2 == 1`

Non-integral division in Python 3:

`3 / 2 == 1.5`

What you're talking about is not a division by all means.

Comment: Although perhaps you could point out that Python 3 does floating point division by default, Python 2.6 did integral by default.

Comment: FWIW, Python 2.6.1 (not 3): `3/2 -> 1`, `3.0/2 -> 1.5`, `3.0//2 -> 1.0`

Answer (score 4):

The intent of the OP's question is **"How to implement division with round-towards-infinity in Python"** (suggest you change the title).

This is a perfectly legitimate rounding mode as per the [IEEE-754 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008#Rounding_algorithms) (read [this overview](http://www.eetimes.com/design/programmable-logic/4014804/An-introduction-to-different-rounding-algorithms)), and the term for it is "round towards infinity" (or "round away from zero"). Most of the 9 downvotes were beating up on the OP unfairly. Yes, there is no single-function way to do this in native Python, but we can use `round(float(a)/b)` or else subclass `numbers.Number` and override `__div__()`.

The OP would need to clarify whether they want -3/2 to round to -2 or -1 (or don't-care for negative operands). Since they already said they don't want round-upwards, we can infer -3/2 should round to -2.

Enough theory. For implementations:

- If you just want the fast-and-dirty one-line solution for round-towards-infinity , use `round(float(a)/b)`
- `math.ceil(float(a)/b)` gives you round-upwards, which you said you don't want
- But if this is your default division operation, or you are doing a lot of this, then do like the pseudocode below: [inherit from one of the subclasses of `numbers.Number` Real, Rational or Integral (new in 2.6)](http://docs.python.org/library/numbers.html), redefine `__div__()` or else define a non-default alternative `__divra__()` operation. You could define a class member or classmethod `rounding_mode` and look it up during divisions. Be careful of `__rdiv__()` and mixing with ordinary floats though.

.

```
import numbers

class NumberWithRounding(numbers.Integral):
    # Here you could implement a classmethod setRoundingMode() or member rounding_mode
    def __div__(self,other):
        # here you could consider value of rounding_mode, or else hardwire it like:
        return round(float(self)/other)
    # You also have to raise ImplementationError/ pass/ or implement the other 31
    # methods for Float: __abs__(),...,__xor__() Just shortcut that for now...
```

Answer (score 2):

When you divide two integers, the result is an integer.
`3 / 2` equals `1`, not `1.5`.
See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex), note 1:

> For (plain or long) integer division, the result is an integer. The result is always rounded towards minus infinity: 1/2 is 0, (-1)/2 is -1, 1/(-2) is -1, and (-1)/(-2) is 0. Note that the result is a long integer if either operand is a long integer, regardless of the numeric value.

Once you get `1` from the division, there is no way to turn that into `2`.

To get `1.5`, you need floating-point division: `3.0 / 2`.
You can then call `math.ceil` to get `2`.

You are mistaken; there is no mathematical function that divides, then rounds up.
The best you can do is write your own function that takes two floats and calls `math.ceil`.

Comment: ...or be using Python 3. Python 3 does floating point division by default.

Comment: @Null: That's because I didn't finish yet.

Comment: But if you read the question carefully, the OP specifically asks for something that's not rounding up or ceiling

Comment: @Null: You're right; I didn't notice that.  This is the closest he'll get.

Comment: I don't think there is a valid answer for this question; I know no arithmetic operation between 3 and 2 that yields 2.

Comment: @Null: it's called ["round towards infinity" (or "round away from zero")](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_away_from_zero) as I comment above. **Division with round-towards-infinity** would indeed be a single legitimate **mathematical** operation which gives this result (it's rarely implemented on FP hardware, which is what you meant). The OP could subclass [numbers.Number or its subclasses](http://docs.python.org/library/numbers.html), redefine __div__() or define __divra__()

Comment: @Franklin: He wants to always round up

Comment: @SLaks, no. If he wants to round +1.5 → +2 and -1.5 → -2, then it's _round-towards-infinity_ (_round-away-from-zero_). If -1.5 → -1, then it's _round-upwards_ (which he said he doesn't want).

Comment: @SLaks you are referring to Python 2.x, even the docs you linked notes that.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is something like:

```
math.ceil(3.0/2.0)
# or
math.ceil(float(3)/float(2))
```

You could also do an import from future:

```
from __future__ import division
math.ceil(3/2) # == 2
```

But, if you do this, to get the current behavior of integer division you need to use the double slash:

```
3 // 2 == 1 # True
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you're looking for is this:

assuming you have x (3) and y (2),

`result = (x + y - 1) // y;`

this is the equivalent of a ceiling without the use of floating points.

Of course, y cannot be 0.

Answer (score 1):

Integer division with ceiling rounding (to +Inf), floor rounding (to -Inf), and truncation (to 0) is available in gmpy2.

```
>>> gmpy2.c_div(3,2)
mpz(2)
>>> help(gmpy2.c_div)
Help on built-in function c_div in module gmpy2:
c_div(...)
    c_div(x,y): returns the quotient of x divided by y. The quotient
    is rounded towards +Inf (ceiling rounding). x and y must be integers.
>>> help(gmpy2.f_div)
Help on built-in function f_div in module gmpy2:
f_div(...)
    f_div(x,y): returns the quotient of x divided by y. The quotient
    is rounded towards -Inf (floor rounding). x and y must be integers.
>>> help(gmpy2.t_div)
Help on built-in function t_div in module gmpy2:
t_div(...)
    t_div(x,y): returns the quotient of x divided by y. The quotient
    is rounded towards 0. x and y must be integers.
>>>
```

gmpy2 is available at http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/

(Disclaimer: I'm the current maintainer of gmpy and gmpy2.)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you want to be using floating-point division in the arguments.  Use:

```
from __future__ import division
```

If you always want to round up, so `f(3/2)==2` and `f(1.4)==2`, then you want `f` to be `math.trunc(math.ceil(x))`.

If you want to get the closest integer, but have ties round up, then you want `math.trunc(x + 0.5)`.  That way `f(3/2)==2` and `f(1.4)==1`.